# How to use an array of names as name of a radio button group?

Tags: php, html, arrays, radio-button

I'm developing php page for "Online Test"
I've maintained a database for question-answers and the options of the same. What I'm unable to do is assigning different names to a group of radio buttons for the options.
Here's the code :

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT ques,ques_ans.q_no,A,B,C,D from ques_ans JOIN options ON ques_ans.q_no=options.q_no";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$radiogrp=array();
for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++){
    $radiogrp[$i]="q".$i;
}
for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++){
    echo $radiogrp[$i];
}
foreach($radiogrp as $rg){
while($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $myrow["q_no"]."  ";
    echo $myrow["ques"]."<br><br>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<input type='radio' name='$rg' value='Option A'/><?php echo $myrow["A"]; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='$rg' value='Option B'/><?php echo $myrow["B"]; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='$rg' value='Option C'/><?php echo $myrow["C"]; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='$rg' value='Option D'/><?php echo $myrow["D"]; ?><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

I want to change the radio button group name as the new question is retrieved from the database.

Comment: Since this is a test it shouldn't be any issue: But do not post database connections anywhere on the internet. Other than that for this question it is just useless information!

Comment: Okay Thank you for letting me know about the database connectivity @AlexG

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as you did here `<?php echo $myrow["A"]; ?>`

See the following:

```
name=' <?php echo $value; ?>'
```

If this is not what you're looking for please describe your problem better.

Comment: Or use the short Syntax: `<?= $value; ?>`

Comment: Described as I want to change the radio button group name as the new question is retrieved from the database. @Scorpion Code

Comment: @Diksha when you fetch the data from the datbase you can use as well `echo` and what you did in the while loop. So `echo $myrow['value'];`

Comment: Okay so I'll have to make a column in the table for the radio group name? That's what you mean to say i think.

Comment: Yes I could do that but its an array of names. So how to do that with the array?? @AlexG

Answer (score 0):

It got solved!
Just moved the radio buttons in php tags and added one more condition in the `while` loop and changed the value of `name` attribute to array-name with the subscript.

```
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$radiogrp_name=array();

for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++){
    $radiogrp_name[$i]="q".$i;
}
$i=0;
while(($myrow=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && ($i<$numrows)){
    echo $myrow["q_no"].". ";
    echo $myrow["ques"]."<br><br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='Option A'/>".$myrow["A"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='Option B'/>".$myrow["B"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='Option C'/>".$myrow["C"]."<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='$radiogrp_name[$i]' value='Option D'/>".$myrow["D"]."<br><br><br>";
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Now the question arises that how would I retrieve the values of these radio groups :/  I tried accessing the array but it gives what is set in the array(i.e the names) and not the value of radio button... Any suggestions will be of great help :)